# Value of $c$ for the distribution of a discrete variable $X$

Tags: probability, statistics

> Consider the function $f(x) = c(x^2 + 3x + 4)$. For what value of the constant $c$ will the function $f$ serve as the probability distribution for a discrete random variable $X$ taking on only the values $X\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$? State your answer to three decimal places.

I plugged all the values for $X$ in $f(x)$ and summed them together to obtain $$2c+ 2c +4c+ 8c+ 14c=1\implies 30c=1\implies c=\frac{1}{30}$$ I'm not sure if this is the right answer though. Is that the right procedure?

Comment: Yes - that is the correct procedure, though not stated "to three decimal places"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the correct procedure. Since $f$ is to be a probability mass function we require that $\sum_{\text{all }x}f(x)=1$, which is precisely what you have. Indeed,
$$\begin{cases}f(-2)=c\left((-2)^2+3(-2)+4\right)=2c\\f(-1)=c\left((-1)^2+3(-1)+4\right)=2c\\f(0)=c\left((0)^2+3(0)+4\right)=4c\\f(1)=c\left((1)^2+3(1)+4\right)=8c\\f(2)=c\left((2)^2+3(2)+4\right)=14c\end{cases}$$
and 
$$\sum_{x\in S}f(x)=30c\qquad S:=\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$$
so your answer is also correct.

The only thing that is now required (as Henry pointed out in the comments) is to give the value of $c$ to three decimal places, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Though you can slightly simplify your calculation.

Since the random variable is discrete, it must be the discrete probability distribution. According to the probability axiom:
$$\sum_{x=-2}^{2} f(x)=1 \Rightarrow \sum_{x=-2}^{2} c(x^2+3x+4)=$$
$$c(\sum_{x=-2}^{2} x^2+3\sum_{x=-2}^{2} x+ \sum_{x=-2}^{2} 4)=c(2\cdot 5+3\cdot 0+5\cdot 4)=1 \Rightarrow 30c=1 \Rightarrow c=\frac{1}{30}\approx 0.033.$$